# Как получить root к android с помощью macosx?

Tags: android, sdk, root, adb

Всем привет!

У меня китайфон Servo h1 с кучей левых рекламных программ с иероглифами и бесконечной ошибкой "в приложении youtube возникла ошибка". Отключать системные приложения - не вариант, все равно включаются, только выпилить из системы.

Мои планируемые действия

1) Включить отладку по юсб
2) Получить рут доступ, чтобы удалить вшитые программы с вирусней и пропустить через антивирус
3) Привязать аккаунт гугл, настроить и наслаждаться

Минус этого решения - после хардрезета (сброса настроек телефона) все говно восстановится, но не суть, прошивать не собираюсь.

Отладка по юсб включена. Далее я действовала по инструкции https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCqebSxUItw

У меня уже заранее скачаны инструменты sdk и мои действия были такими:

```
Home-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools home$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
64976194914246  device

Home-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools home$ ./adb reboot bootloader
Home-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools home$ ./fastboot oem unlock
< waiting for device >
```

Короче, после fastboot все стопорится ((( При этом, adb устройство определяет.

Если что - пожалуйста, сильно не пинайте, до китайфона юзала кнопочные телефоны и в андроидах вообще не смыслю

Comment: У каждого андроида свои собственные особенности, тут лучше гуглить конкретные инструкции для конкретной модели. И да, лучше перепрошить (если прошивки на это устройство вообще есть)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что для тюнинга смартофонов есть специализированные форумы.

Comment: Перепрошивать не рискну - народ, перепрошивавший этот аппарат, жалуется на зеркальное отображение символов и другие мелкие косяки.

Comment: Под mac инструкций на 4pda нет. Перепрошивка под виндой. У меня проблема в получении root инструментами fastboot и adb, после чего я бы удалила лишнее.

Comment: `adb` и `fastboot` это разные режимы. Если фастбут не видит телефон - значит он не перешел в этот режим после предыдущей команды(которая собственно и переводит телефон в режим фастбут)